# How can I manipulate the DOM using the chrome extension javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a chrome extension that is similar to the [Toucan extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toucan-language-learning/lokjgaehpcnlmkebpmjiofccpklbmoci?hl=en)

For example I have this example.html without the extension
[image: Example]

When I loaded the extension of Toucan it will manipulate the DOM of the website it will change some text content of the

tag. Unfortunately, I don't have any idea how to achieve this in javascript. (I have knowledge about content, background and popup in manifestation json.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The general direction is to use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) (defined in the extension manifest), that contains something like the following:

```
let paragraphs = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));
```

Then, you can modify the first paragraph using

```
paragraphs[0].innerText = "new text";
```

Comment: I want to modify the CSS attached of that tag

Comment: @MoshMobileSoftwareEngineer Then just modify paragraphs[0].style instead. For instance, `paragraphs[0].style = "color: blue";`